# (ipconfig /displaydns) - how to display details for specific domain name

Tags: windows, dns, ipconfig

When I issue **`ipconfig /displaydns`**, I get a ton of output.  I want to display the details for a specific domain name like **`google.com`**.  My objective is something like this as output:

[image]

I tried **`ipconfig /displaydns | find "google.com`"**, but this did not help me as it only displays the lines, not the section

Answer (score 1):

Do `ipconfig /displaydns > file.txt` and use a text editor to find the entry.

Comment: can you please provide me more details on this?

Comment: Which details ?

Comment: what do you mean by > file.txt
I dont want to copy the result to txt file and search there, totally useless

Comment: So what are you searching? A script for extracting 8 lines?

Comment: I want to display a section like display the result of only google.com from ipconfig /displaydns, because there are a lot of entries in the output:
!
https://i.postimg.cc/W4rtpdVW/2018-11-24-22-22-24-Command-Prompt.png

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend PowerShell for this. Open PowerShell and type this command:

```
Get-DnsClientCache | ? { $_.Entry -eq "google.com" }
```

You could also search partial matches using the `-like` operator:

```
Get-DnsClientCache | ? { $_.Entry -like "*google.com" }
```

You can use `Out-GridView` (`ogv`) to open a pretty GUI window which will let you filter on any field as you type:

```
Get-DnsClientCache | ogv
```